# Problem with Masking values of 2 different text box to masked text box

Tags: c#, maskedtextbox

My Masked Text Box Mask is :
000/000
I want to display the value of a textbox1 to the first half of the mask and textbox2 value to the other half.
textbox1/ textbox2
How to do this ?

Comment: Do you just want the mask value split into the other two textboxes or do you want user input of the masked textbox placed into the two textboxes?

Comment: TextBox1.Text = "233";
TextBox2.Text = "111";
I want these 2 values to be showed together in the masked textbox in this format :
MaskedTextBox.Text = 233/111

Answer (score 1):

You are probably  going to have to create a function which does the string concatenation and places the value inside your `masked textbox`, you'll need to wire this up to each `Textbox.TextChanged` `event` so that when the user types a new character, the `Text` property of the `masked textbox` gets updated:

```
//Text changed event for textBox1
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //If null set to empty
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text ?? "";
    SetMaskedTextbox();

}

//Text changed event for textBox2
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //If null set to empty
    textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text ?? "";
    SetMaskedTextbox();
}

private void SetMaskedTextbox()
{
    //Just concatenate the textbox values with the "/" and set it to the masked textbox .Text
    maskedTextbox.Text = textBox1.Text + "/" + textBox2.Text;
}
```

Comment: Didn't realize it would be that simple. Thank you.

Comment: @Parnalp Do you have the events wired up to your textbox1 and textbox2?

Comment: Ya I set the text change events for both the tetxbox, but if I change the mask to 0/0 until the value reaches 9 , it shows properly but when it goes 2 digits.. again there is a problem.

Comment: @Parnalp That would seem to be because you have the mask set to `O/O` so it only accepts single characters on both sides of the `/`, try increasing that to hold larger amounts of characters `OOO/OOO`, you will also probably want to restrict the amount of input in your textbox1 and textbox2 if you have a limit for your mask.

Comment: For Mask : 0/0 -> Values are showed until 9 and then the values change to 1/0
For Mask 00/00 -> For the first 9 values it displays 88/__
For Mask 000/000 -> It also works the same as the above mask and displays 88_/___

Comment: @Parnalp So, what do you want it to do? Prepend zero's on the front of the input for both textboxes?? If textbox1.Text = 1 and the mask is set to display as `OOO/OOO` then prepend `00` to the front of the 1 in textbox1.Text, do the same with textBox2.Text You can do this check inside the `TextChanged` events.

Comment: Yaa.. Thank you again.